# Determining resistors in a Wheatstone Bridge from Ohmmeter readings - Unsolvable system of equations

Tags: resistors, wheatstone-bridge, ohmmeter

I have been challenged in an assignment that uses a Wheatstone bridge to find values for the resistances in each arm, given that they are 1 kOhm +- 1%, and using only Ohmmeter readings and short-circuits between the 4 bridge terminals.

My attempt was measuring 4 parallel resistances like so:

[image]

obtaining Req for 4 different pairs of adjacent arms.

These values came out as: 0.506, 0.506, 0.509 and 0.509 (kOhm)

When I try to use parallel resistance equations to solve for the R1 to R4 values, i get:

[image]
through substitution, but that ends up indeterminate (the R1's cancel out).
Is this method not suitable for my goal?

Edit: fixed parallel expression in schematic

Comment: In your figure you meant Req = R1 || R4, right?

Comment: Yes, I will add a note. Thank you

Comment: Is the short-circuit connection in place for all measurements?  If so some of the equations are incorrect. For example the measured value of R2 will be dependent only on the value of R2 in parallel with R3, (due to R1 and R4 section being shorted).   In your first equation what is Rj and Ri ?  Also ,you are not defining which positions you are measuring the 0.506 k, 0.506 k, 0.509 k, 0.509 K ohm values.

Comment: No, the measurements correspond to essentially 90 degree rotations of the schematic, i.e., to measure R1||R2 the short-circuit is applied by connecting the node between R2 and R3 with the node between R4 and R1.

Since I am not getting any solution for a system, the positions for the values obtained aren't immediatly relevant, but they are:

R1||R2 = 506 Ohm;
R2||R3 = 509 Ohm;
R3||R4 = 506 Ohm;
R4||R1 = 509 Ohm;